# Password Protected directory not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

My password protected directory is not working.
i have setup the `.htaccess` file withing the directory to make it protected.
i have placed `.htpasswd` file in the root.
setup the path for .htpasswd in .htaccess but after entering true password it still ask for password.
i have put encrypted password in .htpasswd.

my .htaccess code

```
AuthName "Please Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswd      
require valid-user
```

my .htpasswd code is like this

```
user:encryptedpassword
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong or what should i check

Comment: You should add the .htpasswd info as well, just to make sure it's formatted correctly. Remember to encrypt a different password so people don't get your real pass. And you shouldn't store the .htpasswd file in public_html, move it out of the public scope.

Comment: my .htpasswd file is like user:encryptedpassword.

Comment: You can still use http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php as alternative for htaccess protection

Comment: solved myself. just need to check the root path of the cpanel using this code. this is the code $doc_root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

Comment: Please, answer your own question.